# How to configure different ExpireTimeSpan for persistent and non-persistent cookies in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a sign-in page with remember me option. I want to configure remember me cookie expiry to be quite longer, say one month. I could use the `CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan` property but that doesn't work "only" for RememberMe option. I want the user to be signed in for few minutes, like 30 minutes after sign-in, in the current browsing session (if the user didn't select RememberMe option). In this case I would use `ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)`.

Is there a way I could configure something like "RememberMeDuration" to configure two different settings when RememberMe is selected and when not selected? - out of the box (at least not creating the whole new middleware for such small feature)

Answer (score 4):

Absolute expiry can be used to implement Remember Me (say for 30 days) feature.
When using Identity, set the `ExpiresUtc` during `SignInAsync` after password check.

```cs
var au = new ApplicationUser() { Email = model.Email };
var r1 = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(au, model.Password);
if (r1)
{
    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(au, new AuthenticationProperties() { ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30) });
}
```

If Cookie Middleware without Identity is used then set the ExpiresUtc after customized password check is successful.

From the docs:

```cs
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", principal, new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30)
    });
```

`IsPersistent` and `ExpiresUtc` are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Hi bvoleti. Thanks for the workaround using CheckPasswordAsync and then SignInAsync. However, if I use ExpiresUtc, I'm going to lose the IsPersistent and with that effect, the sliding expiration would not work.

This would be my last choice as I want to try something that allows me to keep the sliding expiration still active in its place.